# I cant get a Link to center with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using GitHub Pages btw.
Anyway, I cant for the life of me get this to work!

Here is my html Code(A link for a youtube page:

```
<a href="notgoingingtoshowthislink" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
```

And my CSS:

```
   a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  top: 550px;
}
```

So far the link is white and the right size, it is just not centered!
Many thanks!

Comment: If you're using other CSS as well, try adding "!important" right after center

Comment: doing this didnt work Ill try using div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add text-center to the parent div and not the the element itself.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="center-this">
    <a href="notgoingingtoshowthislink" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#center-this    {
    text-align:center;
}
#center-this a{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! this worked. I think I get it now, to center it I have to adress it diffrently then when I chnage the color!

Answer (score 2):

As flyingeagle431 suggests, you could add `!important` to it. Another way of doing this is putting it in a `div` class and centering the contents.

CSS

```
.link {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.link a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="link">
    <a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xso2m7hL/)

Comment: YAYYY! its centered, but now it is not white, anyway to fix that?

Comment: You do not use `!important` unless you __NEED__ to override certain style. No need for `DIV` parent, just make element `block-type`.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping andrew fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

`a` tags are `display:inline` by default, which means they'll only be as wide as the content. `text-align:center` only centers the content within its container. If you want to center the entire link you need to either make it a `block` or `inline-block` element and set its margins or set `text-align:center` on its parent element. I personally prefer the latter:

CSS:

```
p.centered {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="centered"><a href="whatever">Your Link</a></p>
```

Comment: Precisely, it's about element being inline type.

Comment: Its centered but still not white!, see the page here http://saildesign.github.io/

Comment: Thanks guys! andrew fixed it for me!